# How to draw dots equally spaced along a path?

Tags: metapost

Is it possible to draw dots with Metapost so that each dot is separated from its first neighbour by the same distance along an arbitrary path?

**I do not want their real distance to be regular!** Rather, I want their distance **measured along the path** to be equal.

I want to illustrate **uniform curvilinear motion** with that (and the **uniformly varying** one later).

For instance, I could want to put equally spaced dots along this line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\everymplib{input mpcolornames; beginfig(1);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}
    \begin{mplibcode}
      draw (0,0){right} .. (2cm,4cm){up} .. (4cm,5cm){right} .. (5cm,6cm){up} .. (8cm,7cm){right}
           withpen pencircle scaled 2pt;
    \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want "arclength"...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To follow this solution, you might like to look up "arclength" and "arctime" in [the Metapost manual](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf), or read my explanation below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\everymplib{beginfig(1);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}
    \begin{mplibcode}
        path P;
        P = (0,0){right} .. (2cm,4cm){up} .. (4cm,5cm){right} .. (5cm,6cm){up} .. (8cm,7cm){right};
        draw P withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor .7 white;
        s = 5mm;
        for t=0 step s until arclength P: 
          drawdot point arctime t of P of P withpen pencircle scaled 4pt withcolor red; 
        endfor
    \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- To work with a path it's helpful to save it as a variable.  MP has several sorts of variables `numeric`, `pair`, `path`, `string` and so on.  If you just assign to a variable, as `s = 5mm;`, MP assumes that it's `numeric`.  So to save a `path`, you have to declare it first:

  ```
  path P;
  P = (0,0).....
  ```

  You can then `draw` it, or shift it about or rotate it etc.
- You can also find out how long it is using `length P`.  But MP has a rather curious notion of length, that Knuth christened `time` in the Metafont Book; the length of a path in MP time units is essentially the same as the number of points you used to define it, which is 5 in the current example.  So you can do this:

  ```
  \begin{mplibcode}
  path P;
  P = (0,0){right} .. (2cm,4cm){up} .. (4cm,5cm){right} .. (5cm,6cm){up} .. (8cm,7cm){right};
  draw P withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor .7 white;
  for t=0 upto length P: 
    drawdot point t of P withpen pencircle scaled 4pt withcolor red; 
  endfor
  \end{mplibcode}
  ```

  to produce

  [image]

  but as you can see the dots are not evenly spaced in this particular path, because they just appear at the five points used to specify it.  You can have fractional time, so you could change the loop to

  ```
  for t=0 step 1/4 until length P: 
    drawdot point t of P withpen pencircle scaled 4pt withcolor red; 
  endfor
  ```

  and get:

  [image]

  but this just makes it more obvious that `time` is rather variable on a bendy path.

  However MP provides two more operators that give you absolute length instead of `time`.

  - `arclength P` returns the length of path `P` in PostScript points
  - `arctime a of P` returns the time `t` along path `P` where `subpath (0,t) of P` would have `arclength` equal to `a`.  Got that?

  Using these facilities you can make the step value of your loop a real length, and use `arctime` to find the appropriate `time` along `P`.  The only drawback of this is that the syntax becomes rather cumbersome.  You don't need to add parentheses, but they might make it clearer:

  ```
  point (arctime t of P) of P
  ```

  This gets us to the diagram shown at the top with dots spaced every 5mm along `P`.